# fatal error detected by JRE with jvisualvm

Tags: java, ubuntu, visualvm, jvisualvm

I'm trying to run `jvisualvm`. The odd thing it doesn't work 90% of the time and leaves this error:

complete error: http://pastebin.com/fPF4QgkF

first lines of error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fda78e35880, pid=4065, tid=140577382409984
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 13.04, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.13.04.2
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libglib-2.0.so.0+0x164880]  _fini+0xd8f54
#
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in the graphics library. I would make sure you OS and drivers are up to date.

This appears to be the most up to date OpenJDK 6, but perhaps you can try Oracle HotSpot 6 update 45 or OpenJDK 7.